# How to get the return value of controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-controller

In MVC4, I am trying to use the one controller method in another controller method using `RedirectToAction` but it shows error while try to receive the returned value of other controller's method.

I have following controller method:

```
public class TranslationController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Search_Query()
   {
        List<Surah> Records = new List<Surah>();
        Records = RedirectToAction(" Load_Surahs", "Surah_CRUD");
        ...
        return Json(new { key = Records }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

**Another controller method:**

```
public class Surah_CRUDController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Load_Surahs() 
    {
         List<Surah> Records = new List<Surah>();
         ...
         return Json(new { key = Records }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

how to fix it, i mean i want to use `Load_Surahs` returned list of objects in `Search_Query` method...

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of `Load_Surahs()` to JsonResult

Comment: Could you give us the error you are seeing? You will also need to modify the return of the Search_Query method to JsonResult.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
public ActionResult Load_Surahs() 
        {
             List<Surah> Records = new List<Surah>();
             ...               

             return RedirectToaction("Search_Query","TranslationController ", 
                                      new {jsData = "Your Json data here" });
        }
```

And in your other action use

```
public ActionResult Search_Query(Json jsData)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place method GetSurah in separate service.And use this service in both controllers.

```
public class TranslationController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Search_Query()
   {
       List<Surah> Records = someService.GetSurah();
       ...
       return Json(new { key = Records }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}


public class Surah_CRUDController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Load_Surahs() 
    {
         List<Surah> Records = someService.GetSurah();
         ...
         return Json(new { key = Records }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```